# How to transfer Full Control ACL to named administrator account from CMD prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, acl, icacls

Trying to give my named Administrator account (the account I use to log in to Windows) Full Control ACL permission across ALL files and folders.

What is the command line to do this and/or could someone link me to a guide that explains all possible syntax for ACL alterations from the Command Line (Tried /help but it's quite vague).

**I'm trying to effectively give Full Control to my named account (which is an Administrator account) across the entire main C:\ drive.** However, I want to target that specific account, not the 'Administrators' account group.

Comment: For the most part the administrator already has full control by default to everywhere.  Can I ask why you need to do this?  It may help give you better answers for your specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I'm trying to effectively give Full Control to my named account

This can be done using `icacls`.

```
icacls "c:\" /grant:r UserName:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

Explanation of switches and arguments:

- `/grant :r UserName:permission`

  Grant access rights, with :r, the permissions will replace any previously granted explicit permissions (for the given user). Otherwise the permissions are added.
- `(OI)` - object inherit
- `(CI)` - container inherit
- `F` - Full access (Edit_Permissions+Create+Delete+Read+Write)
- `/T`  Traverse all subfolders to match files/directories.

  This will apply permission changes to all subfolders whether or not they are set to inherit permissions from the parent. On very large directory structures this may take some time as the command has to traverse the entire tree.

You might also want to add the following switches:

- `/C`  Continue on file errors (access denied) Error messages are still displayed.
- `/Q`  Quiet - suppress success messages.

See [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) for a complete list of options and arguments.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) - Change file and folder permissions - display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Dave! Seemed I was missing the quotation marks from the drive letter.

Comment: Do you need more help? If this was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to upvote/accept it. See [accept an answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).